# How to find the calling convention of a third party dll?

Tags: c++, dll

Could any one explain me how to get to know the calling convention of a dll without getting and processing method names? Lets say our application is loading a third party dll and in order to handle it, is there any effective ways to get to know the calling convention of a dll? (__stdcall, __cdecl, __fastcall)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If the symbol begins with a `_` but has no `@`, then it's `__cdecl`. If it begins with `_` and has a `@` it's `__stdcall`. If it begins with `@` and has another `@`, it's `__fastcall`.

[source](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv.html)

Comment: Thank you very much Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams. Is there any other effective way to find out it? is there any library functions to get the calling convention?

Comment: This of course assumes the DLL is compiled by MSVC, as the linked article says in the introduction. It also assumes there's no DEF file used. Just try to find the calling convention used by USER32.DLL by this method - doesn't work.

Comment: How about `thiscall` (not asked by the OP, but anyway)? Does the symbol start with a `?` ?

Answer (score 2):

While trying to figure out why I was getting unresolved symbols when linking against a third-party dll I stumbled upon a (sort of) programmatic solution.

I wrote a small program against the Windows API using `UnDecorateSymbolName` from `Dbghelp.h`to decode the mangling scheme:

```
#include "Windows.h"
#include "Dbghelp.h"
#include "tchar.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CHAR out[512];
    UnDecorateSymbolName(
        // Mangled symbol
        "?OFFReader@IO@OpenMesh@@YGAAV_OFFReader_@12@XZ",
        out,
        // Length of symbol
        46,
        UNDNAME_32_BIT_DECODE);
}
```

There are definitely prettier ways to do it. I just run it in a debugger and look at the contents of out.

Also worth noting, contrary to Ignacio's answer, the difference between the mangled names for the `cdecl` methods in the dll and the `stdcall` methods being looked for was `YAAAV` vs. `YGAAV`.