# Which calling convention is used for functions exported via .def file?

Tags: c, visual-c++, calling-convention

I'm compiling some third party C code with Visual C++. The source tree contains the following .def file:

```
LIBRARY "ThirdParty.dll"

EXPORTS
   ThirdPartyFunction @1
```

and there's no explicit calling convention specification (like `__stdcall` or `__cdecl`) near `ThirdPartyFunction()` definition. The Visual C++ project properties (C++ -> Advanced -> Calling convention) is set to `__cdecl (/Gd)`.

Which calling convention will be used for the exported function and how do I make sure that it's that convention?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4162419/2065121) may not help, but if you haven't seen it, it's maybe useful.

Comment: @RogerRowland: Actually it does help - I used Depends and looked at the exported symbols and I see they are not decorated and so it is `__cdecl`.

Comment: A __cdecl function is decorated as well, by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A .def file does not control the calling convention, it is purely determined by the compiler.  If you don't explicitly use __cdecl or __stdcall in the function declaration then it is the compiler's default, so __cdecl.  Corner cases are __thiscall for C++ member functions and __clrcall for managed code.

The calling convention also selects the name decoration style, specifically invented to avoid accidents with client code getting it wrong.  __cdecl adds a single underscore before the name, __stdcall appends "@n" where n is the size of the stack activation frame.  Which  protects against a stack imbalance when the client code uses a wrong declaration with a mismatch in type or number of the arguments, a fatal and very hard to diagnose problem with __stdcall.  Disabling this decoration with a .def file is actually a bad idea and should only ever be contemplated if the DLL is dynamically loaded with LoadLibrary+GetProcAddress.  If you intend to have your DLL used by non C/C++ clients then it usually a good idea to use __stdcall explicitly since that tends to be the default for other language runtimes.

None of this matters for 64-bit code, it blissfully has only one calling convention.  Although it looks like Microsoft is [about to mess that up](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/12/introducing-vector-calling-convention.aspx) by adding the __vectorcall calling convention.