# How to verify DLL calling convention in run time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I am developing a `DLL` in `C++` using `Visual Studio 2010`, my DLL calls a function from a third-party DLL.

There are a lot of third-party DLLs with the same name, from many different developers, that provide this same function, my DLL has to be able to work
with each of these DLLs.

The problem is that each developer uses a different `calling convention`, `stdcall`, `cdecl` etc.
Is there any way of my DLL verify in `run time` the calling convention of the third-party DLL?

Comment: There's more than just 2 ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: Possible duplication of this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162400/how-to-find-the-calling-convention-of-a-third-party-dll

Comment: Am I wrong in believing this should be resolved at compile time?

Comment: @PasserBy My code must specify the calling convention of the function, In my case, just in run time is possible to know it.

Comment: @Joe Thanks, but in this link I can't find a solution for "run time".

Comment: These are C++ DLLs right?  Written in C++ and exposing "decorated" function names?  Yes?  In that case, whoever is supplying you with the DLLs should also be supplying you with a header file.  Is that not the case?  And if they are, then the header file should either specify a calling convention (if they want something other than the default) or you should be able to assume that it is _cdecl.   I realize something in my statements here must be wrong but I don't know what it is.  Are they giving you static link libraries or are you using LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress?

Comment: @Joe These are C++ DLLs, I have access to the header and I can verify the calling convention of each third-party DLL, theres dozens DLLs. When my DLL is running, it calls (LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress) a function of the third-party DLL that is located in the same directory and has a standard name, and this DLL could be anyone, of every supplier, with any calling convention. In the moment of the calling, my DLL has to be able to calls any third-party DLL of any  calling convention, if theres a way to verify in run time the calling convention of the third-party DLL, my DLL could call it correctly.

Comment: @Joe A solution is to map in my DLL the names of the third-party DLL's authors and it calling conventions, and in run time to check the author's name in the proprieties of DLL, but theres dozens of third-party DLL, I am looking for another solution. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: You are missing my point.  If the DLLS expose  C++ functions with decorated names, then the signature is baked into the decorated, exposed name itself.  In this case, if you use a link library with that, you have verified the signature merely by linking to it.  If you use LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress instead of a link Library then you can search by various names to check calling conventions.  See this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/deaxefa7.aspx